# Performance issue on using linq query in the razor view

Tags: c#, linq, razor

In an Asp.net mvc project we have a lot of linq queries in the cshtml/razor view in order to fetch the data from the sql instead of using it in the controller. i do also believe that it is not a standard way.But my question is will it cause any performance or loading time for the application?

Comment: It will cause design and subsequent maintenance issues for sure, maybe even before performance becomes one

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you will face any significative performance issue while executing LinQ queries in your views.

**However**, it is a really bad practice to do so. Your views should only take care of presentation, not data access.

[Here](https://www.brainvire.com/six-benefits-of-using-mvc-model-for-effective-web-application-development/) is an article on why you should seperate your concerns.

Hope it helps.